# How to find the spring coefficient of a simply supported beam?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, statics

So I've been searching wikipedia and google but nothing can show how to find the spring coefficient of a simply supported beam with a uniformly distributed load. The spring coefficient, $k$, is related to modulus of elasticity, $E$ and the moment of inertia, $I$. I'd like to be accurate of how this is derived.

Comment: Pull it with a fixed force and measure the displacement. $F=-kx$.

Comment: I want to relate $k$ to $E$ and $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/Courses/ME4730%20Fall%202013/Rand4770Vibrations/BeamFormulas.pdf

$$ \delta = \frac{5 w \ell^4}{384 E I} $$

Stiffness is $k=\frac{F}{\delta}$ $$k = \frac{w \ell}{\delta} = \frac{384 E I}{5 \ell^3}$$